# Does Salesforce have a support system?

Tags: lightning, java, platform-event, support, salesforce-support

Does Salesforce have any support platforms that can offer assistance w.r.t. questions such as:

[403:denied_by_security_policy:create_denied when subscribing to platform events](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/263942/403denied-by-security-policycreate-denied-when-subscribing-to-platform-events)

that have a heightened degree of urgency?

Comment: have you tried to log a case? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workcom_contact_support.htm&type=5

Comment: I added a question through a ticket but the forums seem dead. Do you know other means of support?